# MATLAB's equivalent of "for s in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'): ..."?

Tags: matlab

What is the MATLAB equivalent of (Python's)

```
for s in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'):
    do_stuff_with(s)
```

?

Or, better yet, what's MATLAB's equivalent of

```
for s in 'foo bar baz'.split():
    do_stuff_with(s)
```

?

(I realize that MATLAB discourages using for-loops, but the case I have in mind is one where something like, e.g., a vectorized operation would be hugely impractical.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for s={'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
  do_stuff_with(s)
end


for s =strsplit('foo bar baz')
  do_stuff_with(s)
end
```

This second one is for Matlab 2013a, though

Comment: Note that perhaps slightly unexpectedly, inside the FOR loop, `s` is a single-element cell array.

Comment: Indeed: the above should really be written with `do_stuff_with(s{1})` (which is *pretty* annoying, I must say)...

Answer (score 0):

```
% define your inputs in a cell array
input = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'};

% You can use "regexp" to split the string
input = regexp('foo bar baz', ' ', 'split');

% Or, if you have Matlab R2013a or newer, you can use "strsplit" to split the string
input = strsplit('foo bar baz');

% use for loop to go over each entry of the cell array
for n=1:length(input)
  s = input{n};
  do_stuff_with(s);
end

% Depending on what "do_stuff_with" does, you may use "cellfun" to run do_stuff_with() for each entry of the cell array
do_stuff_with = @(x) sprintf('word: %s',x);
output = cellfun(do_stuff_with, input);
```